# How to pass input to multi element text box which is varying dynamically using selenium with java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

[image]I have one page where it has single text box, same page we have link called "***create account***". When I click "***create account***", page will be added with one more text box(i.e now text box count go to 2, next click 3 text box, next click 4 text box, etc). So whenever we click "***create account***" text box will be added on page.

Now I need to identify how many text boxes available in the column and I need to pass input to those text boxes(*i.e if page has 3 text box, I need to identify those 3 text box and send input, if page has 4 text box, I need to identify those 4 text box and send input*)

Note: All text boxes will be added after clicking ***"Create account"***

When I use following path, I'm able to identify all available text box( 4 text boxes) in the page
***Element css path***: `input.form-url[id^=text-box-]`

How I can pass input to these text boxes using selenium java? How to store input using arraylist and how to pass to this css path elements?

[image: Varying text box]

```
String textBoxSelector = "input.form-url[id^=text-box-]";
String[] texts = new String[]{"firstText", "secondText", "thirdText"}; 
for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)                            
{ 
  driver.findElements(By.id(ADDBUTTON)).click(); 
}
List<WebElement> textBoxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(textBoxSelector));
for(int i = 0; i< textBoxes.size(); i++){
    textBox.sendKeys(texts[i]);
}
```

- //3 inputs texts in array
- // first FOR loop clicks button 2 times. so we get total 3 textbixes( 1
  default+2 clicks)
- //list textBoxes store the 3 text box elements
- //last FOR loop send input values to those 3 text box values

Comment: Can we access that page publicly ?

Comment: Nope..If you need more information let me know!

Comment: Please post the HTML DOM. Have you tried like this? 

1. Click on 'create account' for n times.
2. And use the `List<WebElement>` to get all the available text boxes.
3. Use `for` loop to pass different data's for each text box and I believe you stored that data in excel or some where.

Comment: First clicking on 'Create account' is not a right one i think. Because we need to decide text boxes based on input data stored in one place. If I have 3 input data, I need to click 2 times to get 3 text boxes. So bases on input only we need to decide the clicks . How we can do that? Below answer looks suitable, but where handling "Click" option is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is not problems with waiting until all those elements are loaded and if the input text is a fixed value you can do something like this:

```
String textBoxSelector = "input.form-url[id^=text-box-]";
String[] texts = new String[]{"firstText", "secondText", "thirdText"};
List<WebElement> textBoxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(textBoxSelector));
for(int i = 0; i< textBoxes.size(); i++){
    textBox.sendKeys(texts[i]);
}
```

**UPD**
Updated to use existing input strings array you are already have which length is not shorter that the text boxes amount.

Comment: Here you're passing only one input. But my case I have 4 text box and i need pass 4 different inputs( Input 1- 1st text box, Input 2- 2nd text box, input 3- 3rd text box, input 4-4th text box etc..Future I may get 5, 6 input and text boxes also)

Comment: Well, you did not mention that in the question. See updated answer

Comment: Here we have one more condition, First by default it has one text box only. After I click "create account" text box count will increases. So your code above will send string to fixed no.of text boxes. But my case need to click "create account" to add the second text box and i need to pass url to that second text box. Updated screenshot for reference

Comment: Could you please guide me?

Comment: I certainly can, but I see you are changing what you are asking again and again.  Also, I will not write here complete flow of your test. Stackoverflow is to ask specific problems and to get specific answers to them, not to "please write a project I have to do for me for free".

Comment: I feel I already answered your answer even after you seriously changed your initial question. Now you are welcome to accept and upvote my question. And in case you have NEW, ADDITION questions you are welcome to ask NEW, SEPARATE question(s) per each specific problem you have

Comment: I understood. But its a kind of tricky scenario to mention, that's why I changed my intial question.Also there is small correction in ur answer, you mentioned as textBox.sendKeys(textBoxes[i]); but I hope it should be textBox.sendKeys(texts[i]);
If I have 4 input then I need to click "Click button" 3 times to make the text box count as 4. To handle this I have written following code. Atleast could you please review and share your thoughts?
for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) 
{
driver.findElements(By.id(ADDBUTTON)).click();
}

Comment: You are right about my typo, changing it accordingly, sorry. But I still think it's a new question while I have answered this question

Comment: It's really hard to understand the code when it appears in a comment. I indeed wish to help you

Comment: Also, I'd like to tell you something I feel here. There are some users that are not giving upvote / accept until they receive the complete and the perfect answer to all their question details. As if he was an employer and the person answering him is his employee. But it's not the situation. They do not pay money, just asking for help and other people trying to help them as far as they can for free. In such a situation I think the correct way is to give upvote to everyone who tried to help you and gave something relevant and to accept the best answer between the others if there are several.

Comment: added more details with updated code for your reference. Thanks for your indeed to help on this :)